# How to get a Rails form that is submitted with invalid data to repopulate the user entered fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm working to build a Rails 3 + devise, user registration page. This will be an additional page that does not replace the existing devise registration page. This page will include user info and billing info.

I'm trying to get the form to submit and if the form fields do not save, have the reloaded page include the user's previously inputted data. Here's a snippet:

```
<%= form_for(User.new, :url => '/pricing/sign_up') do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

When the form submits with invalid data. When the view re-renders, the existing email entered is not persisted. How can I make the existing user's input persist to help the user quickly correct mistakes and submit a valid form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to have the `form_for` use the right object. So, instead of

```
<%= form_for(User.new, :url => '/pricing/sign_up') do |f| %>
```

you should be using an instance variable to contain the object, like this

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => '/pricing/sign_up') do |f| %>
```

The controller actions would look like this:

```
# Note: this may need to be an `edit` method instead?
def new
  @user = User.new
end

# Note: this may need to be an `update` method instead?
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    # Do something... Usually a redirect with success message.
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

What this create method is doing is it's filling the `@user` object with params from the form. And then the call to `@user.save` will, behind the scenes, call `@user.valid?` and, if no errors are returned, then the record is saved to the database. But this part is key. If `@user.valid?` does result in errors, then the errors collection on `@user` will be populated. Then, after the `render :new` completes, and re-renders your user form, the form will be able to spit out errors messages by accessing the `@user.errors` collection. Otherwise, the way you had it before, you always had a `User.new` object in the form which would never have had any errors because it was never used to attempt record validation before.

How to display the errors in your form is a matter of preference and a little beyond the scope of this question. Here's a guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because of your `form_for` declaration where you're creating new instance of User on every call.

If you move the `User.new` to your controller and render the `new` action upon failure in `create` action then you should see the user entered values in the form fields.

Something like the following should work:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save 
      ...
    else 
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => '/pricing/sign_up') do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The values of the form fields are driven by the model you pass to `form_for`, so in your case they will always be empty because you are passing a brand new user object.

You should be using an instance variable which is set in the controller; in the `new` action this will be a new `User` model but in the `create` action it will be a model which has attributes set via the form:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = user.create(user_params)

  if @user.save
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Then in the form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => '/pricing/sign_up') do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
<% end %>
```